# Xcode linker error when localizing xib

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, linker, xib

I am just localizing my app and when I localize one certain xib-file, I get a linker error with exit code 1. The file that is duplicate (so tells me the compiler) is always the xib I just localized.

I suppose an internal file list in the xcode project does not recognize the localization BUT... it's just a suspicion ;)

Do you have any idea for the reason of this problem?

Thank you in advance,
Christian

EDIT:
Just found out that the linker error remains when i remove the localized files and reiimport the un-localized file... maybe this helps...

Comment: What is the error message from the linker? Without we can just guess. It is probably not the Xib file, because they are not handled by the linker at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

- to add the file in build phases

  and
- add copied resources

  this [link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/hi-i-faced-this-problem-and-want-to.html) will help

Answer (score -1):

In the left pane, highlight the .xib file and do a Get Info.  Under the General Tab, click on the make localizable button.